# Is it possible to set column default to SQL Server's NewId()?

Tags: fluent-migrator

In fluentMigrator, is it possible to set a column default to a function?

Specifically, I'm adding a uniqueidentifier (Guid) column to a SQL Server 2008 table that already contains data, and it's going to be a required field - is it possible to set the default to the NewId() function?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Field defaults for NewId() and GetDate() are available (for SQL Server at least) by referring to either `SystemMethods.NewGuid` or `SystemMethods.CurrentDateTime`, for example:

```
Create
    .Column("incomeIdGuid").OnTable("tblIncome")
    .AsGuid()
    .NotNullable()
    .WithDefaultValue(SystemMethods.NewGuid);
```